# QSelectSection not saving values when scrolling QuickDialog

Tags: quickdialog

I've been struggling with this for 3 days. The documentation for the QSelectSection is the class itself, and the QuickDialog docs are minimal at best.

I'm trying to use the QSelectSection using the QuickDialog framework. I have it working for most of the controls (after diving head first into the code to see how the component works) but this one has beaten me. From my understanding, and the way the other controls work, this should dump the selected item values into the alerts array within my controller. I want to put as much in the JSON as I can, and only use the controller to store/submit the details if this is possible.

The JSON below generates the dialog and my multi select form. Awesome, but for some reason when I scroll the select section off screen, my values are gone. When I submit the form, the app does not see my selected items. When I try to use "controllerAction" to store these values, the app just crashes.

```
{
  "grouped": true,
  "title": "MyTitle",
  "controllerName": "LOrderViewController",
  "sections": [
    {
      "title": "Notifications",
      "type": "QSelectSection",
      "bind": "selectedItems:alerts",
      "multipleAllowed": true,
      "items": [
        "Email Alerts",
        "App Alerts"
      ],
      "footer": "My Footer text."
    }
...
  ]
}
```

What am I missing? What code is required in my controller, how can I trigger that code?
Am I better off scrapping QuickDialog for something that is better documented, or just stick with native methods?

Love the concept of QuickDialog, but the same isn't holding true for me with this taking so long to learn.

Comment: Have you tried using QRadioSection instead of QSelectSection?

Comment: Hi Dan, if you have found any solution please share. I am having same issue.